# flask database reset migrate

Tags: python, database, flask, database-migration

i have created a database for the Flask application,

```
class Post(db.Model, SearchableMixin):
    __searchable__ = ['body']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    language = db.Column(db.String(5))
    # for the comment foreign key
    comment = db.relationship('Comment', foreign_keys = 'Comment.post_id', 
        backref = 'post', lazy = 'dynamic')
    photo = db.relationship('Photo', foreign_keys = 'Photo.post_idn', 
        backref = 'post', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Post {}>".format(self.body)

class Photo(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        photo_url = db.Column(db.String(200))
        upload_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
        new_field = db.Column(db.String(100))
        post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Photo {}>'.format(self.photo_url)
```

when i run flask db migrate and upgrade, it states that

> [2018-11-25 21:07:03,439] INFO in **init**: Microblog startup INFO 
>   [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl. INFO 
>   [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.

However, when I try to run Photo.query.all() in flask shell, it gives me the below errors ' No such column: post_id'

I believe this is a databse migration issue. Any one has any idea what i should do?

And i am willing to delete the whole database and re-migrate everything again. Can someone advice me how to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have created post_id as foreign key. So you must create a Post model for post db table with a column named id.

Comment: I have the Post Model as well. Sorry that i didnt post above. I already updated.

Comment: In, Post table, did you by mistake mention foreign_keys = 'Photo.post_idn'.

'idn' -- this is wrong, because it refers to post_idn not post_id.

You can simply mention foreign key relation as -- 

photo = db.relationship('Photo', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here to help others.

I had the same problem, I solved it by:

```
flask db upgrade 
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

The first upgrade - is used to apply the initial database schema, creating tables and defining their structure based on your SQLAlchemy models

Migrate - is used to generate a migration script that captures any changes to your database schema. It doesn't apply the changes yet; instead, it prepares a migration script.

The second upgrade - After generating a migration script using flask db migrate, you use this command to actually apply the changes to your database.

- It executes the migration script, which contains the SQL statements to modify the database schema as per your model changes. This updates the database to match your latest model definitions.